# Move everything to SD card on Android Virtual Device (Emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, sd-card, android-sdcard

I need to do a strange task. I want to move whole android system to external SD card on Android Virtual Device. I need to do this, because android emulator, emulates SD commands, only for external card image. And I want to get SD commands trace, during Android Virtual Device usage.

To be more precise: I want to move at least /system and /data folders to external storage. In such way, that system could still work fine =)

Thank You!

Comment: This is not supported.

Comment: @ChrisStratton maybe you can propose some way, to move most of the emulator I/O activity to external SD card?

Comment: As I said, that is not supported.  It's unclear what you hope to gain by this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As I said, "android emulator, emulates SD commands, only for external card image". I need to get SD/MMC commands dump (like WRITE_BLOCK, SEND_STATUS, etc.), during usage of any installable app. For example, I want to see all SD commands, while playing "Flappy Bird", or smth.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, I do not understand, why it is such unclear question for you. I am sorry, but if You don't know what are SD/MMC commands, you can walk through [this reference](http://goo.gl/R9BhIc). If you do not know what is emulation, you better use wiki. So, android emulator emulates SD/MMC commands, ONLY for external memory card. This is not the one, on which system is installed. And I need to get SD/MMC commands dump, from that card, on which system is hosted. As you know some android-linux system folders, are hosted on internal card, like /system or /data.

Comment: I understand, that it could be very strange, but I need to get done this particular task.

Comment: It's precisely because I'm aware of what SD commands are that your assumption that the emulator would model things in that level of detail strikes me as **unlikely** - especially given that Android devices have not relied on actual SD cards for several generations now.  Can you point to any evidence that SD cards are modeled at that level by the official emulator or an alternate one?  **What actual problem are you trying to solve?** - don't tell us the method, tell us the type of information you need to discover, as there are certainly alternative possibilities - ie instrumenting the code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Android emulator does model such things. You can convince yourself by reading description of [goldfish_mmc_do_command() function](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/hw/android/goldfish/mmc.c). Of course, SD cards doesn't widely used, but eMMC does. And eMMC commands specification is mostly same. I suppose, that I was rather precise in my question. Get android emulator's SD/MMC commands dump. That's it. I didn't choose this task, and there is no hidden motivation. If you are interested, in what kind of question I needed, you can read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move some of system folders (/system or /data), to external emulated SD card, you need to do following:

1. Firstly, /data contents (for example) should be placed on sdcard. Initially they are loaded by emulator from userdata.img file. 
   So you need to copy userdata.img `($EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/userdata.img)` contents to sdcard.iso. `$> dd if=userdata.img of=sdcard.iso`
2. I assume, that android virtual device is created. To change boot configuration, you will need to change fstab.goldfish file on ramdisk.img. If it is Android 4.4 AVD, then ramdisk.img could also be find at `$EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/`

   - Create a temporary folder, say ramdisk-ext `$ mkdir ramdisk-ext`
   - Change directory to ramdisk-ext `$ cd ramdisk-ext`
   - Extract the ramdisk.cpio in the ramdisk-ext folder `$ gunzip -dcv ../ramdisk.img | cpio -idm`
   - Modify fstab.goldfish `$ gedit fstab.goldfish` in such way:

     - String #6 from `"/dev/block/mtdblock1    /data ..."` to `"/dev/block/mmcblk0    /data ..."`
   - Create new ramdisk `$ find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip -9 >../ramdisk_new.img`
3. Everything is done, now you need to start the emulator, with your new ramdisk and custom sdcard:`$ ./emulator -avd $AVDNAME -sdcard sdcard.iso -ramdisk $EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/ramdisk_new.img`

P.S. Notice that in this example you can move only one of such folders (/system or /data). Maybe it could be changed, by creating sdcard image with several partitions.